# deepin-anything-dkms error [20.04]

Tags: system-installation, dpkg, error-handling, pkg-config, deepin-desktop-environment

2 days ago I was trying to install DDE (Deepin Desktop Environment). It didn't finish, now everytime I try to install something it gives me this error.

[image: Translation: Errors found while processing:]

What's happening and what can I do?
Edit: It also gives me the following message

> Done.
> Loading new deepin-anything-0.0 DKMS files...
> Building for 5.8.0-50-generic
> Building initial module for 5.8.0-50-generic
> ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/deepin-anything-dkms.0.crash'
> Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-50-generic (x86_64)
> Consult /var/lib/dkms/deepin-anything/0.0/build/make.log for more information.

Edit 2:

```
On /var/lib/dkms/deepin-anything/0.0/build/make.log it shows the following code
DKMS make.log for deepin-anything-0.0 for kernel 5.8.0-50-generic (x86_64)
mar 11 may 2021 13:01:17 PDT
make: se entra en el directorio '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-50-generic'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/deepin-anything/0.0/build/vfs_utils.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/deepin-anything/0.0/build/arg_extractor.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/deepin-anything/0.0/build/vfs_change.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/deepin-anything/0.0/build/vfs_kretprobes.o
/var/lib/dkms/deepin-anything/0.0/build/vfs_change.c: In function ‘copy_vfs_changes’:
/var/lib/dkms/deepin-anything/0.0/build/vfs_change.c:128:3: error: unknown type name ‘time_t’; did you mean ‘ktime_t’?
  128 |   time_t shifted_secs = vc->ts.tv_sec + hour_shift*3600;
      |   ^~~~~~
      |   ktime_t
/var/lib/dkms/deepin-anything/0.0/build/vfs_change.c: In function ‘init_vfs_changes’:
/var/lib/dkms/deepin-anything/0.0/build/vfs_change.c:348:74: error: passing argument 4 of ‘proc_create’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  348 |  struct proc_dir_entry* procfs_entry = proc_create(PROCFS_NAME, 0666, 0, &procfs_ops);
      |                                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                                          |
      |                                                                          struct file_operations *
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/deepin-anything/0.0/build/vfs_change.c:5:
./include/linux/proc_fs.h:108:24: note: expected ‘const struct proc_ops *’ but argument is of type ‘struct file_operations *’
  108 | struct proc_dir_entry *proc_create(const char *name, umode_t mode, struct proc_dir_entry *parent, const struct proc_ops *proc_ops);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:286: /var/lib/dkms/deepin-anything/0.0/build/vfs_change.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Se espera a que terminen otras tareas....
make: *** [Makefile:1783: /var/lib/dkms/deepin-anything/0.0/build] Error 2
make: se sale del directorio '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-50-generic'
```

Comment: How have you tried to install the **Deepin Desktop Environment**? If you followed a guide/tutorial please post it. And why didn't it finish?

Comment: Yes, it still shows me the same error. I think it didn't finish becuase my internet was slow. I had to try to reinstallit 3 times, before it gave me this error.

Comment: How have you tried to install the **Deepin Desktop Environment**? If you followed a guide/tutorial please post it. *Yes, it still shows me the same error* is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Yes, this the guide I was following
https://itsfoss.com/install-deepin-ubuntu/

Comment: Please try the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Well, by this time, I guess the OP might have already got a solution. Anyway, I've faced the same.

@ChanganAuto's answer indirectly have the solution. If you follow the [guide link he mentioned](https://itsfoss.com/install-deepin-ubuntu/), in that page you'll find (probably later added) a section "Fix for deepin-anything-dkms".

In summary, "out-of-the-box" UbuntuDDE has a problem compiling that module under newer kernels (on 20.04, it seems). But, the file it first indicates also doesn't solve the problem. It has predicted there could be newer versions of it, and so you just need to go to http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntudde-dev/stable/ubuntu/pool/main/d/deepin-anything/?C=N;O=A and download newest version of deepin-anything-dkms present there.

As of today (2022-03-15), newest version is http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntudde-dev/stable/ubuntu/pool/main/d/deepin-anything/deepin-anything-dkms_5.0.9-1ubuntu1_all.deb. Installed like a charm.

Still following what that guide says, after downloading, open a terminal session, go to the directory where you've downloaded it and

```
sudo apt install ./deepin-anything-dkms_<the version you've dowloaded>.deb
```

After that, it'll probably finish installing and setting up other dependencies that couldn't be installed previously, like deeping-anything-server, dde-file-manager, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Knowing that you followed an [up-to-date guide](https://itsfoss.com/install-deepin-ubuntu/) (at the time of this writing) and assuming the correct [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntudde-dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable) mentioned in the guide was already added, please run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntudde-dde
```

Some cleanup is probably in order. Do this before the previous commands and then try again:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
```

Comment: still gives me the same error. On the terminal I found this message:

Done. Loading new deepin-anything-0.0 DKMS files... Building for 5.8.0-50-generic Building initial module for 5.8.0-50-generic ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/deepin-anything-dkms.0.crash' Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-50-generic (x86_64) Consult /var/lib/dkms/deepin-anything/0.0/build/make.log for more information.

Comment: So please consult that log file and post what it says, by editing the question

Comment: There we go, I posted the make.log code as an edit.

Comment: Thank you for editing. Please try the two new commands and then repeat the previous ones. I suspect you had an incomplete or corrupt download at some point.

Comment: Still giving me the same error :(, but yes, I was having slow internet and it interrupted the installation process midpoint.

Comment: This is bad... As a last resort try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt install -f`.

Comment: Still not gives me the error :(

Comment: Any updates regarding this issue?
I'm also facing it, although I don't have any problems with the internet connection